# Match up correlating columns in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, match, multiple-columns

I have one column which stays the same. I have data in column B and C which correlate with each other. I want the text and number in column B and C to match up with the text in column A.

Question: How can I successfully sort column B and its correlating column C to match column A?

For Example 
before:

A    C    20
B    E    50
C
D    A    10
E

after:

A    A    10
B
C    C    20
D
E    E    50

I have tried =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$D$23,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$D$23,1,0)) but this only matches column B with column A (based on the example above).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nitpicking: Please ask a question. Also show what you have tried and where you are struggling. This forum is a bit different than others. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on posting questions here.

Comment: Hi guitarthrower. I have tried searching for the answer to no avail. I have tried a few things but I can only seem to manage to sort column B but not its correlating column C. My question is how can I successfully sort column B and its correlating column C to match column A.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Providing the group with the things you have tried prevents people from duplicating your efforts, or simply stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward `VLOOKUP` would work here, with some conditioning on whether the search failed/not:

[image]

Column E has the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$6,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$6,1,FALSE))
```

Column F is similar, only retrieving column 2 from the lookup array:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE))
```

Of course there is some duplication here, since the lookup is performed twice. However, not sure how this would affect you in your use-case regarding performance, since the scope of the question is somewhat limited.

#### Reference

- [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)
- [ISNA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx)
- [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx)